# Como recuperar o IP do usuário utilizando Node

Tags: javascript, node.js

Olá, como posso fazer uma aplicação que "pega" o IP do usuário utilizando o node?

Atualmente meu código está assim:

```
const express = require('express');
const handlebars = require('express-handlebars');
var minifyHTML = require('express-minify-html-2');

const app = express();
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 8081;

// MINIFY HTML

app.use(minifyHTML({
    override:      true,
    exception_url: false,
    htmlMinifier: {
        removeComments:            true,
        collapseWhitespace:        true,
        collapseBooleanAttributes: true,
        removeAttributeQuotes:     true,
        removeEmptyAttributes:     true,
        minifyJS:                  true
    }
}));


// HENDLEBARS
app.engine('handlebars', handlebars({defaultLayout: 'main'}));
app.set('view engine', 'handlebars');


// ROTAS
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.render('home');
});

app.use(function(req, res) {
    res.status(404);
    if (req.accepts('html')) {
        res.render('home');
        return;
    }
});

app.listen(PORT);
```

E o código do Front-End está assim:

```
$.get('https://api.ipify.org?format=json', function(ipv4) {
    var ip = ipv4.ip;
})
```

Estou utilizando JQuery para recuperar o IP do usuário pelo front-end utilizando está API: https://api.ipify.org?format=json, mas gostaria de fazer isso pelo back-end, ou enviar o valor da variavel IP para o node se possível.

A aplicação está assim: https://my-ip-tk.herokuapp.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Utiliza `req.connection.remoteAddress` no processamento da requisição.

Exemplo com várias possibilidades:

```
const ipCliente = req.connection.remoteAddress || req.socket.remoteAddress || req.connection.socket.remoteAddress;
```

Comment: Apliquei o código mas ele me retorna um IP local do servidor acredito eu:

https://my-ip-tk.herokuapp.com/

Comment: Este IP é o seu IP público de internet. No meu caso retornou meu IP certinho (IPv4 em "IP:" e IPv6 em "IP TESTE:") de acordo com o site http://meuip.com.br/ . Cada cliente vai aparecer um diferente, o que você quer é o IP do seu cliente certo?

Comment: Uma observação é que no seu computador de desenvolvimento vai aparecer o IP local da sua rede, o IP do seu cliente só vai aparecer mesmo depois que você publicar a aplicação.